# UICollectionView Assertion failure in createPreparedCellForItemAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview

my code is simple,just want to create a flow layout UIColloctionView

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {
    return 1;
}
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 7;
}

- (__kindof UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [UICollectionViewCell new];
    return cell;
}

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return CGSizeMake(SCREEN_WIDTH / 2 - 5, 160);
}
```

and this is the error

> *** Assertion failure in -[UICollectionView _createPreparedCellForItemAtIndexPath:withLayoutAttributes:applyAttributes:isFocused:notify:], 
>   /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit/UIKit-3600.9.1/UICollectionView.m:2115

Comment: You are working with storyboard or xib??

Comment: @ShabbirAhmad neither，only code

Comment: Just deque the cell like :                                                         
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as the documentation said

> the collection view requires that you always dequeue views, rather than create them explicitly in your code

this is  different from UITableView , just deque the cell all the time

**wrong**:

```
UICollectionViewCell *cell = [UICollectionViewCell new];
return cell;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using dequeue reusability of the collection view cell:

```
- (__kindof UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UICollectionViewCell * cell=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    return cell;
}
```